# PES 2013 via Wine on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wine

I've finally got the game to work on Ubuntu. The thing is it's slow.

This game is the only thing keeping me from totally moving from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 12.10

I would like to get rid of Windows 8 by making this game a bit faster, just a bit.
I've tried Video Memory Size and changed it to 512 MB, my real VRAM. Still slow.

Is there anyway that I can speed the game up a bit?

Comment: You are probably better of asking this on the wine forums or here: http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=313 A few things I noticed: try to turn of/on vsync, framerate and try to use another wine version (you can set those inside POL and/or winetricks)

Answer (score 0):

in command line write : winetricks
that will open a GUI , then choose "Select the default wineprefix"
after that choose "Change settings"
then choose "videomemortsize=defualt"

i hope it works as you want :)

Comment: You seem to have a few typos. Can you please [edit] to fix that. Moreover, can you please expand to say what does it do so that it would solve the problem.